# How Can I use .htaccess to return another file to the client?

Tags: php, .htaccess, download

I want to return the content of "download.php?file=filename" if anybody request "filename.rar"

Comment: I think you should look into `mod_rewrite` - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html and proceed from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.rar download.php?file=$1.rar
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what "RewriteEngine on" does it mean ?

Answer (score 0):

This'll turn your server into a wide open door for anyone to grab any file they want, but... it does what you want.

```
<?php
    readfile($_REQUEST['file']);
```

Enjoy...

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_GET[file]))

 header("Location: PATH TO FILE");
```

OR

```
$filename = 'FILENAME';
$file = 'PATH TO FILE';


header("Content-Disposition:  inline; filename=".$filename);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$fp=fopen($file,"r");
print fread($fp,filesize($file));
fclose($fp);
exit();
```

Comment: you did not read question. he want to turn file.rar to download.php?file=file.rar